# Ng-click and ng-show won't display JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to call specific JSON data from an AngularJS filter. Basically, I want a user to click on one of the otpions from the query/search bar and get related JSON data displayed in another div. Using ng-click and ng-show, I'm able to get the div to show up but I can't get the JSON data to show.

Here's my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.myvalue = false;
 $scope.showAlert = function(){
   $scope.myvalue = true;  
 };
  $scope.schools = [
  {
    "districtcleaned": "Test ISD",
    "campus": "Test school",
    "gradesimplified": "C",
    "level": "Elementary",
  }
  ]
})

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<head>
 <!---AngularJS--->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">              
   <section class="form">
    <form class="form-inline">
     <input class="input-special" ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search school rankings" autofocus>
    </form>
    <ul ng-show="query" class="ng-hide" ng-repeat="school in schools | filter:query | orderBy: 'name' | limitTo: 15">
     <li ng-show="school" class="result">
      <span class="category"><a ng-click="showAlert()">{{school.campus}}</a></span>
      <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{school.level}}</span>
      <span class="category">District: {{school.districtcleaned}}</span>
      <span class="category">Grade: {{school.gradesimplified}}</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="school-details ng-hide" ng-show="myvalue">
     <p>School: {{school.campus}}</p>
     <p>District: {{school.districtcleaned}}</p>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm new to AngularJS and JSON so any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert it. Try: let myJson = JSON.stringify(URJSON, null, 2) then display "myJson"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the variable school outside the ng-repeat block. There school doesn't exist. You should move that div inside the ng-repeat ul element.

Then in angular you have a proper filter for JSON, but here you don't need it. That's for display JSON format directly. You are just accessing properties of objects. By the way here the link to it:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Here your correct example. Clicking on the a element, the details are shown correctly:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.myvalue = false;
 $scope.showAlert = function(){
   $scope.myvalue = true;  
 };
  $scope.schools = [
  {
    "districtcleaned": "Test ISD",
    "campus": "Test school",
    "gradesimplified": "C",
    "level": "Elementary",
  }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">              
   <section class="form">
    <form class="form-inline">
     <input class="input-special" ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search school rankings" autofocus>
    </form>
    <ul ng-show="query" class="ng-hide" ng-repeat="school in schools | filter: query | orderBy: 'name' | limitTo: 15">
     <li ng-show="school" class="result">
      <span class="category"><a ng-click="showAlert()">{{school.campus}}</a></span>
      <span class="category"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{school.level}}</span>
      <span class="category">District: {{school.districtcleaned}}</span>
      <span class="category">Grade: {{school.gradesimplified}}</span>
     </li>
          
          <div class="school-details ng-hide" ng-show="myvalue">
            <p>School: {{school.campus}}</p>
            <p>District: {{school.districtcleaned}}</p>
          </div>
    </ul>
   </section>
  </div>
</body>
```